# CSV access via ADO.NET in 64-bit?

Tags: ado.net, csv, odbc, oledb

In a 32-bit .NET app, I can use this OLEDB connection string to connect to a CSV file via ADO.NET:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\foo;"
```

or this ODBC one:

```
"Driver={{Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}};Dbq=c:\foo"
```

However there apparently arent 64-bit versions of either the OLEDB Jet drivers or the ODBC text driver.

I could parse the CSV line by line or run the app in 32-bit mode, but ideally I'd just like to find a different driver that runs as 64-bit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a driver, but I've been pleased with Sebastien Lorion's CSV reader.  Note that I've never used it in a 64-bit environment, but I'm not aware of any compatibility issues.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: note that MSFT has recently reelased a 64-bit driver which handles CSV. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem and after much trial & error this was what I found that worked:

**1. Enable Adhoc procedures**

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

**2. Install this file on server:**

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en

**3. Use this query format:**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\SQL\;HDR=Yes;','SELECT * FROM [test.csv]');
```

**4. Enable OLE Automation procedures:**

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE with override
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE with override;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexis,

Do you need a driver at all?  If you just need to read a CSV file line by line there are a number of free parsers out there.  If you need to also write out a CSV check out [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I don't *need* a driver, but it would be close to zero effort to install a driver and change the connection string, and slightly > 0 effort to do something else.

Looks like I'll have to do something else though :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to convert my application to 32-bit because I was having the same problem, although with accessing a Microsoft Access Database. I know this will work, but you may not want this solution. If anyone knows the answer to this question I woud love to hear it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck-- in December 2010 Microsoft published a a 64-bit OLEDB driver for CSV and XLSX files!

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617561/i-cannot-open-xlsx-file/4936544#4936544) for download links, install details, connection strings, etc.