# I cannot open .xlsx file

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I want to open an xlsx file, I have tried the below code,but neither does it open nor does it thrown any error.

Can anyone throw any light upon it

```
string path = "C:\\examples\\file1.xlsx";
string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";");
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
cn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", cn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: What does "not open" mean?  You are not opening anything, you are running a query.  The syntax is fine, the lack of an exception would indicate that either dt is filled with rows or that the sheet was empty.  Add Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows.Count) for a basic check.

Comment: I would recommend trying a SELECT expression directly and see what you get back before filling the DT. If the query spits an error add it to the question here. if it doesn't and says it's successful then Hans is correct in that your sheet is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running it on 64 bit Windows? Last time I checked the OLE drivers for Excel workbooks did not work with 64 bit Windows.

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you read Excel workbooks from .NET and works with .NET 2.0+ - including 64 bit Windows.

You can see live samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Joe, you are exactly right.
That was it.
Because it worked in my office which has 32 bit Windows, whereas in my home i have 64 bit.
Thanks Joe

Answer (score 6):

In December 2010 Microsoft (finally!) published a a 64-bit OLEDB driver for CSV and XLSX files.

You'll need the 64-bit [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en). Make sure to download the 64-bit version (`AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`).  You'll need to uninstall any 32-bit Office apps (including Sharepoint Designer!) in order to install it.

If you want CSV, you'll want the `Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)` driver name, but I haven't been able to find a full connection string yet using this driver from OLEDB (although if you have, leave a commend and I'll amend this answer).  Note that 64-bit names are different from the 32-bit versions.

For reading XLSX files, use a connection string like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
 + FilePath
 + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
```

For XLS (pre-2007 Excel) files use a connection string like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
 + FilePath
 + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
```

*Many thanks to [this blog post](http://www.arboundy.com/2010/11/the-microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454701/32-bit-text-drivers-microsoft-access-microsoft-excel-and-text-files-from-a-6/3454742#3454742) for pointing me in the right direction when I ran into the same problem, and for providing content I adapted to write this answer.*

Answer (score 1):

See what this does in your connection string:

Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\" the rest of your connection string is correct I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Phillip's answer make sure to set the TargetPlatform to x86.