# 32-bit Text drivers (Microsoft Access , Microsoft Excel and Text files ) from a 64 bit application on windows 7

Tags: 32bit-64bit

Hi i have an application developed on XP with Text ODBC drivers. But when i deployed on Win 7 with office 2007, i have connection issues.

```
<add key="SQLConnection.TextConnectionString" value="Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=c:\Data\;Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False" />
```

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

---

i have googled every solutions like installing the following

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlblog/how-to-connect-to-file-based-data-sources-microsoft-access-microsoft-excel-and-text-files-from-a-64-bit-application)

Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable (32-bit)

2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components

after all of those, in my datasources(ODBC), it still only shows "SQL native client/SQL server/SQL server native client"

in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

i can see all the x32 drivers, but how can i modify my connection strings to access 32-bit Microsoft Text Drivers or are there any alternative solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it'll work automatically (even on a 64-bit machine) as long as the executing process is 32-bit.

Try recompiling to target x86 specifically.

Comment: "my target set as'any cpu'" -- That's exactly the reason why this answer suggested "Try recompiling to target x86 specifically."

Comment: @Kiddo: Yes -- try changing it to 'x86'

Answer (score 6):

You need the 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en

Then try

```
Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
```

for the driver name.

AFAIK, all 64-bit ODBC drivers from the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 64-bit Redistributable have slightly changed their driver names, I guess to differentiate them from their 32-bit counterparts.

Comment: it won't allow me to install 64-bit Redistributabl cuz my officer product is 32-bit

Comment: It will, you just have to uninstall the 32-bit office, install the 64-bit redist, then reinstall the 32-bit office. Whether you want to go through this pain is your call :)

Comment: I know I am responding to pretty old comment. But above process (uninstall 32-bit office, install 64-bit redist an then re-install 32-bit office) doesn't work. It doesn't allow me to re-install 32-bit office if I have 54-bit redist installed. Any clue to get this resolved now?

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem and the recompiling to target x86 specifically worked!  Note that in order to do this I had to specify the Target CPU in the advanced compiler setting dialog - Project Menu>  Properties> Compile tab> Advanced Compile Options button.

Before finding this forum entry I did install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable (32-bit) but I don't know if that had any affect on this issue.

As mentioned above, when the executing process is 32-bit (in this case compiling against x86 makes the app 32-bit specific) the application will use the drivers from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.

Thanks Cameron.

Comment: I did the same but went ahead and uninstall Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

We were doing this from ASP.Net and got it working on Windows 2012 just by moving the one site into a separate app pool that had "32-bit Enabled" turned on in the advanced settings for the App Pool.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people seem desperate here, I want to offer a few solutions. But, first I want to highlight what a **dated proprietary trash idea from the 90s this is.**

1. Use Unix ODBC to host the text file from Linux which the docs (seem to) claim to support an implementation of the [Microsoft text driver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/850320/creating-an-odbc-data-source-with-the-microsoft-text-driver)
2. A better option would be of course to import the CSV into PostgreSQL.

   1. I would suggest just doing this with `\COPY` and dropping the notion of a CSV.
   2. You can maintain the CSV with PostgreSQL acting as a server with the [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) ([`file_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html)).
3. If you don't want to run an RDBMS, the modern way would be to use SQLite. This is a great idea if you don't need the server/client model.

The ODBC->text interface is especially insane, because ODBC doesn't define configuration beyond connection (so I assume there are lots of assumptions there).