# Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, csv, odbc

I have been asked to port a WinForms app that uses the MVP pattern over to a webpage.  The app, amongst other things, uploads a CSV file to a DataTable and then does some work.

The CSV file is uploaded to the server OK and then read with the following code

```
string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False;Dbq=C:\Temp\";

//check that file exists and in correct format
if (File.Exists(this.WorkingFileName))
{                    
    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Determine number of rows
        string selectCount = "select count(*) from [MyFile.csv]");

        using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(selectCount, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

at this point I get the error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name not found
>   and no default driver specified

Now the code works fine in WinForms but fails on the web.  Is there something I need to change in IIS, my config file or something else to get this code to work? Or is there something more fundamental I need to do?

**Update**

OK so I worked out what was different between my two code versions:  The WinForms version was running as 32-bit, as soon as I changed it to 64-bit it threw the same error. See:
[32-bit Text drivers (Microsoft Access , Microsoft Excel and Text files ) from a 64 bit application on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454701/32-bit-text-drivers-microsoft-access-microsoft-excel-and-text-files-from-a-6)

To fix things I installed the Access 64-bit drivers from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255 but I still get the same error.

If I check my ODBC Data Source Administrator I can see "Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv) | 14.00.47600.1000 | Microsoft Corporation | ACEODBC.dll

So it looks like they're installed OK, so why would it still be failing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I found the problem.  Just to summarise all the parts to my solution.

1. Uninstall any 32-bit Office apps (required for step 2)
2. Install the [Access 64-bit drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255)
3. Re-install any 32-bit Office apps
4. Change the connection string in
   **TWO** places as can be seen [here](https://code.google.com/p/fdotoolbox/source/browse/trunk/FdoToolbox.Express/Controls/Odbc/OdbcText.cs?spec=svn1085&r=1085) to:

   @"Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False;Dbq=C:\Temp\"

Note that:

1. The driver name has been changed to
   Microsoft **Access** Text Driver
2. The delimiter for the file extensions
   has been changed from a semi-colon
   to a **comma**.

I didn't spot the comma change which caused me a lot of pain :-(

Comment: I'm not saying this was an option for you (you didn't affirm or deny the requirement), but what about kicking back to 32 bit? Assuming IIS 7+, did you try running the app pool in Enable 32-Bit Applications mode? Works on my machine! :)

Comment: Yeah, my requirement was to get it working on a 64 bit web server

Comment: Bravo! I've been struggling with this issue for weeks until I found your solution,.

Comment: @openshac the link in point 4 is broken, Can you update that. Thanks

Comment: @JNL Cheers, I've fixed that now.

Comment: While this answer helped me, I was lazy and didn't want to uninstal my 32-bit version of office.  The following link helped me.  Essentially run the driver pack with "/passive" and then remove a registry value afterwards.  http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to the webserver not having the Jet Library installed, which I believe provides the Text Driver. It is probably installed locally due to coming with MS Office (again, I believe this is the case)

Comment: I am running the code on my own PC in both cases so anything that needs to be installed is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the connection string well formed? It seems that the dbq parameter is wrong.

```
"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False;Dbq=**C:Temp\\**"
```

Also take a look at this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile), provides useful connection string samples

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo, yes I managed to insert a typo into my connection string in my original post. I have corrected the original question now.