# OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' reported an error

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I'm trying to run this code:

```
<%
Dim rsSelectOrder
Dim rsSelectOrder_numRows

Set rsSelectOrder = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsSelectOrder.ActiveConnection = MM_conn_to_mhwebdb_STRING
rsSelectOrder.Source = "SELECT * from " & ActinicPersons &" p, " &ActinicOrders&" o WHERE p.    [Contact ID] = o.[Invoice Contact ID] AND o.[Order Number] NOT IN ( SELECT OrderNumber from    dbo.tbl_OrdersEntered )"
rsSelectOrder.CursorType = 0
rsSelectOrder.CursorLocation = 2
rsSelectOrder.LockType = 1
rsSelectOrder.Open()

rsSelectOrder_numRows = 0
%>
```

Using the following connection:

```
<%
' FileName="Connection_odbc_conn_dsn.htm"
' Type="ADO" 
' DesigntimeType="ADO"
' HTTP="true"
' Catalog=""
' Schema=""

Dim ActinicPersons, ActinicOrders, ActinicOrderLines, ActinicPayments
ActinicPersons = "OpenRowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};          DefaultDir=C:\inetpub\ActinicOrderFiles\;','select *  FROM persons.csv')"
ActinicOrders = "OpenRowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};      DefaultDir=C:\inetpub\ActinicOrderFiles\;','select *  FROM orders.csv')"
ActinicOrderLines = "OpenRowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};      DefaultDir=C:\inetpub\ActinicOrderFiles\;','select *  FROM orderlines.csv')"
ActinicPayments = "OpenRowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};      DefaultDir=C:\inetpub\ActinicOrderFiles\;','select *  FROM payments.csv')"
%>
```

Unfortunately even running this code in server management I see the following error message:

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".

Any ideas on how to fix it? I have setup DSN for the connection

Comment: It sounds like the account that your SQL server is running under does not have permissions to read your .csv files.  What happens when you run these SQL commands via Query Analyzer or SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem between x32 and x64 drivers, which would be throwing the "driver not found" error.

Try this: [Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490543/data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)