# How to populate IDataReader from .csv for use with SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Someone mentioned today that using the IDataReader version of WriteToServer (Note: Data is stored in a .csv file) would be quicker than using datatables for large .csv files. Unfortunately im struggling to find information on how this actually works/should be implemented.

only link i found is below:

> http://www.developerfusion.com/article/122498/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-high-performance-inserts/

1. Where is the data actually stored?
2. Would i be importing one row at a
   time?
3. How do you split about specific characters ie ',' in this
   case?

Is this something which is quite tricky?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export). It explains how to read a CSV using the ODBC provider for text, and then use `SqlBulkCopy` to import it into a DB. For example:

```
using(var con = new OdbcConnection(
    "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.csv)};" +
    "Dbq=c:\\somepath\\;" + 
    "Extensions=csv"))
{
   con.Open();
   using(var cmd = new OdbcCommand("select * from [" + myCsvFileName + "]", con))
   {
      using(IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
           // Do whatever
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying bro. Both you and Joe are suggesting the same method which is reassuring.

Comment: Consider 64 bit problems with Microsoft Text Driver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454701/32-bit-text-drivers-microsoft-access-microsoft-excel-and-text-files-from-a

Answer (score 1):

One way to bulk insert data from a large CSV file would be to read the CSV file using [OLE DB Provider for Jet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175866.aspx).

You can use a Schema.ini file to describe your CSV file format, and pass an OleDbDataReader as a parameter to the `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` method.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So this method would be quicker than using the datatable approach?

Comment: Potentially quicker for very large files, as it avoids the need to load all the data into memory at once.