# Handling empty fields in csv during bulk import to database

Tags: c#, csv, sqlbulkcopy, idatareader

I'm importing geocode data to our database from a csv file.

I've used the following library 
[A fast csv reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader?msg=4391186#xx4391186xx) to  read the csv and then using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Here's an example of the data I'm importing

```
"AB10","1BH","L",0,0,,,20
"AB10","1BR","L",39320,80570,57.14214,-2.11400,21
```

It works ok on good data but on the top line it will throw an exception because the database is set up to not accept null values.

Is there a way to tell bulkcopy to ignore bad data?  I've tried to get the csv reader to ignore bad lines by using the in built properties of the library like so but they don't appear to work.

```
csv.SkipEmptyLines = true;
csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ParseError;
csv.DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.AdvanceToNextLine;
```

I guess another option would be to pre-parse the csv and remove all the offending rows.  Perhaps there's a better csv library out there for .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with the null entries I ended up parsing the csv into a DataTable object 1000 entries at a time and then imported them as I went.

Answer (score 1):

If you could post your csv reader code then we could help more.  But looking at the code on your linked page, you could do something like this:

```
while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1};",
                          headers[i],
                          csv[i] ?? "null"));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

See where I have added that null-coalescing operator?  This should change your output from:

```
"AB10","1BH","L",0,0,,,20
```

to

```
"AB10","1BH","L",0,0,null,null,20
```

Comment: I've got it working by parsing the data from the csv class into a DataTable class and doing some data validation on the values.  The saving the DataTable directly.  It works pretty well and is very fast but it would be nice if the csv library supported it directly so I've emailed the author asking about it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Microsoft Text Driver to import CSV information for a project. It worked pretty well. I defined a Schema.ini file to specify the column headers, data types, number of rows to scan (MaxScanRows=0, will scan the whole file).

I haven't tried this but when you use Microsoft Text Driver you issue a select query to pull the data out of the csv file, I'm wondering if you could add criteria to filter out the null records.

[How to populate IDataReader from .csv for use with SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535246/how-to-populate-idatareader-from-csv-for-use-with-sqlbulkcopy-writetoserverida)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile

Hope this helps.