# JDBC ODBC Driver Connection

Tags: java, macos, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I'm currently working on a project for a class at my University. I am learning about connecting and manipulating databases and we are using a Microsoft .accdb file.

Here is what I have so far.

```
/* Perform database operations */
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Lab3.accdb");
        System.out.println("Database connected");

        statement = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("");

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            output.write("<p>" + resultSet.getString(1) + "\t" +
                resultSet.getString(2) + "\t" + resultSet.getString(3) + "</p>");
        }

        connection.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException|SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Database Access Error.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When looking for "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" I am getting the following output.

```
SEVERE:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at changepass.ChangePasswordServlet.processRequest(ChangePasswordServlet.java:47)
at changepass.ChangePasswordServlet.doGet(ChangePasswordServlet.java:83)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

It seems simple enough to work through. It seems I am missing the driver or something along those lines. However I am having a hard time finding out what to do about this. Is the driver included with the JDK anywhere? Must I download something separate? Does it depend on my Operating System? (Mac OS X 10.9). Or am I simply doing something wrong in code?

I would appreciate the help! Thanks!

Additional Info:

```
[James@toodarkpark: ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
[James@toodarkpark: ~]$
```

Comment: I think the ODBC bridge is only available on Windows systems. And besides: it's going to be removed in Java 8 completely.

Comment: have you added jar files?

Comment: what is the JDK that you are using...?

Comment: [James@toodarkpark: ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

This is what I have. What JAR files do I require? Any idea where to download them?

Comment: Even if you had a Jdbc-Odcb bridge for MacOS X you need ODBC itself and then you need an ODBC driver for MS Access. Lots of things you most probably don’t have.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420653/odbc-connection-to-ms-access-on-ubuntu/13428683#13428683), it may give you some hints, especially SQLite suggestion ;)

Comment: Yeah I did some more research and a_horse_with_no_name hit the nail on the head. I'm just going to boot into a Windows 8 VM and take care of this assignment there. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: the answer provided in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17381638/3004530) worked for me

Comment: The answer provided in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17381638/3004530) worked for me

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, the JDBC-ODBC Bridge is - as the name indicates - only a mechanism for the JDBC layer to "talk to" the ODBC layer. Even if you had a JDBC-ODBC Bridge on your Mac you would also need to have

- an implementation of ODBC itself, and
- an appropriate ODBC driver for the target database (ACE/Jet, a.k.a. "Access")

So, for most people, using JDBC-ODBC Bridge technology to manipulate ACE/Jet ("Access") databases is really a practical option only under Windows. It is also important to note that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge <strike>will be</strike> has been removed in Java 8 (ref: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html)).

There are other ways of manipulating ACE/Jet databases from Java, such as [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) and [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/). Both of these are pure Java implementations so they work on non-Windows platforms. For details on how to use UCanAccess see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work with ODBC-Bridge for me too.
I got the way around to initialize ODBC connection using ODBC driver.

```
 import java.sql.*;  
 public class UserLogin
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        try
        {    
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            // C:\\databaseFileName.accdb" - location of your database 
           String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\emp.accdb";

            // specify url, username, pasword - make sure these are valid 
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");

            System.out.println("Connection Succesfull");
         } 
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

          }
      }
  }
```