# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:login SQL Server 2014 in java

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2014

```
String sql = "Select * from table1 where username=? and password=?";

try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:login");
    System.out.println("you made connection");
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, usernameInput.getText());
    pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());

    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Login successful");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Login unsuccessful");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

I am trying to connect my database in my application but it doesnt work in Java. it says: no suitable driver found. I searched for answers here but no answer solved my problem. I use SQL Server 2014

Comment: Did you import the library correctly?

Comment: Yes. I use eclipse so they are 100% correct

Comment: Have you created the login source in ODBC ?

Comment: The JDBC/ODBC bridge was removed in Java 8 - and it never was a good thing to use in the first place. Use the JDBC driver supplied by Microsoft or the jTDS driver instead. Much faster anyway

Answer (score 0):

This may have already been answered, see [JDBC ODBC Driver Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709843/jdbc-odbc-driver-connection)

Two things to note: the JDBC-ODBC bridge was removed in Java 8, and even if you have it, you need to have the ODBC driver configured underneath it.

Here are Microsoft's instructions for creating the ODBC name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403320(v=sql.120).aspx