# unexpected output while using sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcDriver

Tags: java

I want to insert a row into an Excel sheet using Java but instead of getting expected output, I get an output as sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.Driver. I am using JDK 1.6.0

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

class ins
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try

        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSNxls");

            Statement st=con.createStatement();

            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your firstname.");
            String fnamej=sc.next();

            System.out.println("Please enter your middlename.");
            String mnamej=sc.next();


            System.out.println("Please enter your lastname.");
            String lnamej=sc.next();


            st.executeUpdate("insert into [Sheet1$]    values("+fnamej+","+mnamej+","+lnamej+")");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `System.out.println(e.getMessage())` to `e.printStackTrace()` and post the stack trace in your question so we can se what is going on.

Comment: i forgot to share that i create a system dsn called DSNxls by going to Control panel->administrative tools->Data Sources(ODBC)

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcOdbcDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)

Comment: this is wat i get after i made changes

Comment: i read this page on stackoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709843/jdbc-odbc-driver-connection

Comment: but is there any other way of fixing this?

Comment: @IshutaWankhede are you using java 8? this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change `sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcOdbcDriver` to `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`, i.e. capitalize 'J'.

Comment: hey...but now m getting new problem

Comment: C:\jdk1.6.0\bin>javac ins.java

C:\jdk1.6.0\bin>java ins
Please enter your firstname.
ishuta
Please enter your middlename.
umesh
Please enter your lastname.
wankhede
[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 3.

Comment: please provide stacktrace.

Comment: i changed the line of code...replaced double quotes by single

Comment: st.executeUpdate("insert into [Sheet1$]    values("+fnamej+","+mnamej+","+lnamej+")");

Comment: but it adds the entry as fnamej  mnamej  lnamej

Comment: finally done...changed the line as follows   st.executeUpdate("insert into [Sheet1$] values('"+fnamej+"','"+mnamej+"','"+lnamej+"')");

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Java 8 to solve this problem or download some jar files and make a few code changes.
Here is the link of a video which will help you completely:

https://youtu.be/DhuafZrlWq4

Comment: No, the problem was an incorrect class name. See the answer given in 2017, where the OP explains that it was fixed.