# how to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Tags: java, ms-access, database, applet, java-web-start

can any one explain me how to fix this issue in my program here i am using Microsoft access whose name is db1.mdb

```
import java.sql.*;
 public class Sample
 {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                try
                {
                        //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                        String url="jdbc:odbc:db1";
                        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:pro");
                        Statement st=con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select idno from regs");
                        int s=rs.getInt("1");
                        System.out.println(s+ " ");
                        con.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                        System.out.println(" "+e);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible dupicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709843/jdbc-odbc-driver-connection

Comment: I am guessing you are using JAVA 8 where in this has been removed.