# connection between java and ms access

Tags: java

I want get data from ms access with my java app. java version 1.8. I watched video from youtube. there was these code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try  {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Test");

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "Select *  from playlist";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e){   
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

my output is:

```
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
Process finished with exit code 0
```

what am i doing wrong? if there extras i have to do? please help!

Comment: what is the error that the code is giving you?

Comment: Have you created DSN with name Test?

Comment: I have seen a couple of questions about a driver named ucanaccess (U can access). I haven’t got any experience and cannot recommend either way, but you may want to investigate yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JdbcOdbc bridge driver was removed from Java in version 8.

[Here is an answer with more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709843/jdbc-odbc-driver-connection)

Your exception contains more useful information than only the message, try printing the exception or printStacktrace method