# Accessing Excel as a database using groovy.sql

Tags: excel, jdbc, groovy, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to access Excel as a database using the [groovy.sql](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/sql/package-summary.html) package, which is a GDK extension to JDBC. I am aware that Excel is not a database and that for most tasks [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) works better. I am using an Excel file named *weather.xlsx* as a test document. The workbook contains only one sheet which looks like this:

[image: Sample Excel file]

| City | Temperature |
| --- | --- |
| Denver | 19 |
| Boston | 12 |
| New York | 22 |

I am using this code:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class ExcelAsDB {
    static void main(args) {
        def sql = Sql.newInstance(
                """jdbc:odbc:Driver=
                {Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
                    DBQ=C:\\path_to_file\\weather.xlsx;READONLY=false""", '', '')

        println "City\t\tTemperature"
        sql.eachRow('SELECT * FROM [temperatures$]') {
            println "${it.city}\t\t${it.temperature}"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver=
                {Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
                    DBQ=C:\path_to_file\weather.xlsx;READONLY=false
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:396)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$newInstance.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at Excel.main(Excel.groovy:7)
```

I've read in similar questions such as [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Exception occurring. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurri) and [JDBC ODBC Driver Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709843/jdbc-odbc-driver-connection) that the ODBC bridge was removed from Java with Java 8. However, I was under the impression that if I connect directly to the Excel driver, rather than setup a DSN for the Excel file, I should be able to access the file anyway.

I am using a Windows computer and have confirmed that the Excel Driver is installed. I am using Groovy Version: 3.0.8 JVM: 16 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have both 32- and 64-bit versions of the Excel driver ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Looks like I only have the 64-bit version.

Comment: And is your groovy installation running 64-bit ? Sometimes this 'driver not found' stuff is due to different 'bitness'. Not necessarily your root cause, but worth checking.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I'm using a 64 bit operating system, and I downloaded Groovy using the installer, which I believe checks and downloads the right one.

Comment: Jdbc-odbc bridge has been removed from java 8+. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html I know that people copying jdbcOdbc.dll from java 7, but it's risky...

Comment: Java 8 doesn't have the JDBC-ODBC bridge, so it does not support the `jdbc:odbc:` URL prefix.