# JDBC driver MS Access connection

Tags: java, odbc

I want connect my MS access file with Java GUI program,but I have problem with connection....

I have Windows 7 64b, and ms office 2007.
When I opened the ODBC driver manager in the control panel I havent found any driver for Microsoft Access (maybe when I started the ODBC is started running the 64bit ODBC, now I think is running the 32bit ODBC. 
I read this and I make it : 
"jdbc-odbc connection for window 7 64 bit machine..
 1 . Right click Data source (ODBC)..go to properties change the folloing thing

target [ %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe ]
 start in : [ %SystemRoot%\System32 ]

press enter and continue as admin               source: [source link](http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/)
" 
) Now when I start in conctrol pannel the ODBC I can see the driver [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMosk.png)

My program code(I tried two ways but I have same error):

```
        public void Connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

 //    String DatabaseFile = "D:java/Invertory.mdb";       
//            String DATABASE =
//                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver="
//                    + "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
//                    + "DBQ=" + DatabaseFile;`enter code here`
 String DATABASE ="jdbc:odbc:Driver= Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=Invertory.mdb";
           CONEX = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE);

        } catch (Exception X) {
          X.printStackTrace();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

error

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: Have you verified that the ODBC component was installed when you installed Access?

Comment: I dont remember, but now i reinstall the ms office 2007.

Comment: This is the direct path don't need to create a new System DSN, you probably need to check your path to the `.mdb` file.

Comment: I used this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Of4LRHOZoII           in the video the code is working.but for me is not. I reinstalled all but it allowed the ms office but still have a same errror.

Answer (score 15):

Use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC Driver :

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://<mdb or accdb file path>",user, password); 
for example: 
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/pippo.mdb");
```

So for your example it will be `Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+path)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 64-bit you probably need to go to this path

> C:/Windows/SysWOW64/odbcad32.exe

Then I noticed that you are using the direct path instead creating new `System DSN`, your direct path is correct till the path to the *access* file you must give the full path like this :

> jdbc:odbc:Driver= Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=path/to/Invertory.mdb"

To get the path you probably need to use `java.io.File` that have a method returns the abslute path to the file see the example :

```
import java.sql.*;
public class TestConnection {
    Connection con ;
    Statement st ;
    ResultSet rs ;
    String db;
    public TestConnection (){
        try{
            String path = new java.io.File("Invertory.mdb").getAbsolutePath();
        db ="JDBC:ODBC:Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb); DBQ="+path;
            doConnection();
        } catch(NullPointerException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    public void doConnection(){
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Invertory");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
            }
        }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());

        }

    }
    public static void main(String...argS){
        new TestConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: String DATABASE ="jdbc:odbc:Driver= Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=C:/Users/Kex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/database_form/database_form/Invertory.mdb";                                                                                   
            String DATABASE ="jdbc:odbc:Driver= Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=C:\\Users\\Kex\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\database_form\\database_form\\Invertory.mdb";                                                   I tried two way but doesnt work.still error after start. I am at: C:/Windows/SysWOW64/odbcad32.exe

Comment: I tried put this code after and before the "String DATABASE ="jdbc:odbc:Driver= Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=C:/Users/Kex/Documents/NetBeansProjects/database_form/database_form‌​/Invertory.mdb"; String DATABASE ="jdbc:odbc:Driver= Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb, *.accdb);"  and now I have something else: "java.lang.NullPointerException" tht means I connected to access file?

Comment: no, in this function no   here is: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wfym48e5mkso83p/TzmBVCeUhZ

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289655/how-to-connect-to-a-32-bit-access-database-from-64-bit-jvm/10290227#10290227) a while back.

Basically at that time:

1. You could connect to Ms-Access from 32 bit java through the JDBC-ODBC bridge
2. You could not connect to a 32 bit Odbc driver through the JDBC-ODBC from 64 bit java. There was a message telling you that you can only connect from a 32 bit programs
3. While Microsoft does provide a 64 bit Ms-Access driver, it did not work with Java's 64 bit JDBC-ODBC driver.

Since then there seems to be a new open-source Ms-Access JDBC Driver [Ms-Access JDBC driver](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). I have no Idea how good it is.

Answer (score 0):

You just missing something in your code right here :

```
db ="JDBC:ODBC:Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb); DBQ="+path;
```

You need to add `{}` between `Driver=` and `)=;` . 
Like this Below

```
db ="JDBC:ODBC:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="+path;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String fileName = "c:/myDataBase.mdb"
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+fileName;
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
```

Comment: Please describe what you are doing too.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you should run on Java 32 bit try to install latest JDK and it will work

I run it using JDK version **"jdk-7u67-windows-i586.exe"**

Answer (score -1):

On a 64 bit system, you should:

1. run as admin accessdatabaseengine_64.exe
2. run java - 7-64 bit - jre.

Answer (score -1):

if you are working in  NETBEANS then after unzipping ucanacess.zip file add all jar file in the classpath using property window of project click on compile tab and add jar file then compile and test app.

Answer (score -1):

JDBC-ODBC MS-ACCESS CONNECTION STOPPED WORKING IN JDK8. I solved the issue by installing JDK7 along with JDK8 in the same PC, once installed JDK7 I assigned it as the JDK version to use in my project as follows in Netbeans:

1.RIGHT CLICK THE PROJECT IN THE LIST > CLICK PROPERTIES

2.CLICK LIBRARIES ON THE LEFT NAVIGATION TREE

3.CLICK BUTTON MANAGE PLATFORMS > CLICK BUTTON ADD PLATFORM...

4.FOLLOW WIZARD, DESPITE IT SHOWS JAVA STANDARD EDITION CLICK NEXT

5.NAVIGATE TO C:\Program Files (x86)\Java AND SELECT THE FOLDER OF JDK7 > CLICK NEXT

6.THE FIELD AUTOFILL WITH THE RIGHT INFO... > THEN CLICK FINISH

7.SELECT THE JDK PLATFORM FROM THE LIST > CLICK CLOSE > OK

8.JDK7 SHOULD SHOW IN LIBRARIES PACKAGE.

[JDK7 in Libraries Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btVVv.png)
Click Back in Browser to return here after looking at the image...

From here on everything must run smoothly.

Hope it solves your problem.

Thanks.