# 32 and both 64 bit JDBC in java at same time

Tags: java, jdbc, x86, odbc, 64-bit

Scenario: I have installed a 32-bit ODBC driver to connect to database A, and a 64-bit ODBC driver to database B.

I know that I can connect to a 32-bit ODBC driver in java x86 and to a 64-bit ODBC driver in java x64, but what if I need to use a 64-bit ODBC driver and a 32-bit ODBC driver in the same Java application?

Can I connect to both a 32-bit ODBC driver and a 64-bit ODBC driver in Java?

I'm very curious about it.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, and should be reworded to correct/clarify. "ODBC:JDBC" suggests you're trying to make an ODBC client application connect through a JDBC driver (via ODBC-to-JDBC Bridge), but everything else you've said suggests you're really trying to do is make a Java JDBC app connect through a couple of ODBC drivers (via JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Can I connect to a 32-bit ODBC:JDBC and both to a 64-bit ODBC:JDBC in java?*

No. You cannot. It is not possible to invoke 32-bit native code from a 64-bit JVM. However, ODBC should be ODBC - ***if*** you have a 64-bit ODBC:JDBC driver then it should work to connect from 64-bit Java.

Comment: As a follow up to this answer, OP should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289655/how-to-connect-to-a-32-bit-access-database-from-64-bit-jvm). It's not possible to connect to a 32-bit ODBC via a 64-bit Java application as you've mentioned already.

Comment: None of this is quite accurate. See my answer.

Comment: @TallTed Technically, this is completely accurate. You are calling a second JVM to act as a bridge; thus you still require a 32-bit JVM (or at least a 32-bit ODBC driver and a some sort of host) to run the 32-bit native code.

Comment: I am not calling a second JVM. You're correct that it's not possible to make a Type 1 JDBC connection from a 32-bit JVM to a 64-bit ODBC driver, nor from a 64-bit JVM to a 32-bit ODBC driver — but both of these can be made as Type 3 JDBC connections. OP did not ask, "Can I make _a **Type 1** JDBC connection_ to both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC drivers from either 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?" She asked "Can I make _**a JDBC connection**_ to both ...?"

Comment: @TallTed OP's question was *what if I need to use a 64 bit driver and a 32 bit driver in the same application?* In n-tier design, each tier is an independent application. I would prefer the database's type-4 JDBC driver over a ODBC bridge. Or an ETL process if that simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

***Yes,*** you can

- ***use a 64-bit ODBC driver from a 32-bit JVM***
- ***use a 32-bit ODBC driver from a 64-bit JVM***
- ***simultaneously use a 64-bit ODBC driver and a 32-bit ODBC driver from the same Java application, in either a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM***

You just need to use a Type 3 JDBC connection -- a "multi-tier" JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge -- such as the [Enterprise Edition JDBC Driver for ODBC Data Sources](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-mt/) from [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/), to bridge the "bitness" gap.

A Type 3 JDBC-to-ODBC connection puts a "pure Java" JDBC Driver in the JVM with your Java app, and this communicates via TCP/IP with some C-based ODBC Client components that go in the "native" OS environment with the ODBC driver(s) -- which need not be on the same host as each other, and neither need be on the same host as the JVM.

```
Type 3 JDBC Driver in 32-bit JVM
   -> ... TCP/IP ... 
      -> 64-bit ODBC Bridge Middleware
         -> 64-bit ODBC Driver
```

or

```
Type 3 JDBC Driver in 64-bit JVM
   -> ... TCP/IP ... 
      -> 32-bit ODBC Bridge Middleware
         -> 32-bit ODBC Driver
```

You may choose to use a Type 1 "single-tier" JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge such as the [Lite Edition JDBC Driver for ODBC Data Sources](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/) from [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/) that matches the bitness of the JVM and one ODBC driver (let's say 64-bit, here), and use the "multi-tier" JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge only for the other (32-bit) ODBC driver.  *Remember that [Java 8 and later no longer include the Sun JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge (classname `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`, used `jdbc:odbc:<dsn>;UID=<uid>;PWD=<pwd>` URLs) in the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29501476/241164).*