# Is it possible to read csv file using 32 bit Microsoft text driver in 64 bit application

Tags: winapi, odbc, 32bit-64bit, text-driver

I have a requirement where i need to import some data from CSV file using Microsoft Text Driver.
My development environment is:-

Windows7 64 bit
Office 2007 (32 bit)

when i try to open a connection it gives me error:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Is it possible to read csv file using 32 bit text driver and 64 bit application?

Comment: I take it compiling 32bit code is out of the question ?

Comment: My requirement is import data using 64 bit application and 32 bit driver.

Comment: Then from what I see [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454701/32-bit-text-drivers-microsoft-access-microsoft-excel-and-text-files-from-a), you're requirement isn't possible to meet without writing a custom marshaller of some kind. That the ACE drivers for both 32 and 64bit Office can't exist on the same machine is apparently a subject of much "opinion" directed at MS from a plethora of dissatisfied developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit processes can't load 32-bit DLLs.  You'll have to have a separate 32-bit application that reads the CSV files and stores the data somewhere (e.g., your database).